# Is VMWare Fusion bought through the MacUpdate Spring 2012 Bundle a full valid version?

Tags: vmware

I'm considering buying VMWare Fusion 4. On [vmware.com](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/overview.html) it's available for $49.99. MacUpdate is currently also offering a bundle which includes VMWare Fusion and 10 other apps, for a total price of $49.99 ([MacUpdate Spring 2012 Bundle](http://www.mupromo.com/)). I'm not particularly interested in any of the 10 other apps, but they might be nice to have. I'm wondering if there's a catch to this offer though. For example, I seem to remember that a similar bundle offered in the past didn't include the right to discounts when upgrading to future versions. So is buying VMWare Fusion through this bundle fully equivalent to buying it through VMWare.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the answer of Diago, I got this from [the MacUpdate FAQ](http://www.mupromo.com/bundlefaq) :

> **What's the catch?**
>
> There isn't one! You get the exact same versions of the apps as if you
>   paid full price! The same support, update, and upgrade options are
>   available to you, as well.

So, yes! Buying the spring bundle will give you a full valid version!

Comment: +1 For a more official answer. I was just looking for this on the site but my searching skills failed me today.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**

Bundled software, specifically those sold by MacLegion and MacUpdate are 100% fully licensed versions of the applications. I bought Parallels 6 this way last year, and recently upgraded to 7 using the upgrade price without any issues.

MacLegion and MacUpdate sell 4 bundles a year, and they spend a significant amount of time negotiating the deals with the companies that offer the bundles. Since they have build such a good reputation, they tend to come up with some very legit and good deals.

Unless explicitly specified these are full licenses with no string attached. I have bought around 75% of the software I run this way, and one of the reasons I love owning a Mac.

These specials are Cyber Monday coming early.

<sub>I can confirm that outside of MacLegion and MacUpdate, I have bought bundles where this is not the case, however, those were small, not as well known bundle suppliers, and the software clearly stated that they don't qualify for updates.</sub>

Comment: @WheatWilliams I am not sure how I am not answering that. Yes you would. It's a fully valid license, and every piece of software I have bought in this method I have upgraded, including Parallels as I mentioned.